# Using class style inside php code (edit the style of a text from database)

Tags: php, mysql, css

```
echo '<br />'.utf8_encode($article["texte_article"]);
```

I would like to have the text to use a css class "art". $article is a table, and texte_article is the selected column in the database.

```
echo '<br />''<div class=\"art\">'.utf8_encode($article["texte_article"])</div>;
```

It was a try but didn't work. Do you know why my syntax doesn't work/where I should put the class "art" ?

Comment: Should not need to escape double quotes. Also looks like single quote issue. Try: `echo '<br /><div class="art">'.utf8_encode($article["texte_article"]) . '</div>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in string concatenation.  try this:

```
echo "<br /><div class='art'>".utf8_encode($article["texte_article"])."</div>";
```

Comment: This answer seems to be a duplicate of the existing one from four minutes ago before you posted this one.

Comment: Except you left the unneeded `<br>` in :) A `<div>` is a block element, meaning it pushes all other elements to the next line, like a `<br>` does

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting to add the end of the div in as a string, and you so it is messing up your php:

```
echo '<div class="art">'.utf8_encode($article["texte_article"]).'</div>';
```